# How to check if a user inputted value is valid?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app in which the user has the option to input a set of coordinates in two EditText views for Latitude and Longitude. The inputted coordinate/location will then be displayed on a map, which works great. However if the user inputs an invalid value the app crashes, and I need to prevent that.

The Latitudes/Longitudes value has to be for example 35.27, and the thing that makes the app crash is when there's more then one dot "." e.g. 33.23.43. How can i check if the inputted value only has ONE dot?

I don't really have a lot of experience in this area, and I'm still new to android, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you know that the input should only take 1 dot, use a regular expression to detect numbers only with a maximum of one period. I'm not sure if you're handling the map the right way though. How many users will know exact coordinates? Rather, a better way would be to integrate your Google maps with the Google Places API. This will allow a user to search for a location, which will query the API, and you will get an autocomplete, and the user clicks the autocomplete location, and then you get the lattitude/longitude from that.

Comment: I don't know anything about latitude/ longitute. Would it be valid if the user inputted 5.7, or what about 156.175?

Comment: @jcw Yes, it would, but not if e.g. 5.7.1

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for the app crash?

Comment: @DanielSmith no I don't, i'm using google maps api v2, and can't get it to run on the emulator..

Comment: You should be able to get a stacktrace from the logcat... though this is from my experience using real devices

Comment: @Jakob i am able to run maps api v2, just need to install two apks and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest that you checked the length of the string that you get, but because 1.5 and 153.163 are both valid that doesn't work. I advise you to use a `try/catch statement. For example

```
try{
    //do what ever you do with the numbers here
catch(Exception e){
//the user has inputted an invalid number deal with it here
}
```

Comment: huh! I'm sure I've already tried something like this, but i guess i made a mistake. Thanks Mate!! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Check out

[Android EditText : setFilters Example : Numeric Text field Patterns and Length Restriction.](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-edittext-setfilters-example-numeric-text-field-patterns-and-length-restriction/)

It may be what you want.

Comment: I don't think that works correctly if a user pastes multiple characters at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool badInput = countChar(s, '.')  > 1;
```

where countChar is

```
int countChar(string s, char c)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) {
        if( s.charAt(i) == c ) {
            counter++;
        } 
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: What if the user is European and types a ',' or another char?

Comment: @bluewhile One could use `DecimalFormatSymbols#getDecimalSeparator()` and pass that in. The question says `.` and hence I used `'.'` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `regexp` to check the validity of the input.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-)?\d*(\.\d*)?$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if (m.find()) { 
    ////Found
}
else {
  //Not found
}
```

Now Implement a `focus listener` on the field to run this validity test.

**OR :** you can do this from xml also.

In XML add attribute to `editText` :

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

for **signed floating point number**.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need one more `\ ` to escape backslash in your regex .